# CSS to React components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I started rewriting CSS into React Components but i've encountered a problem, I do know how to do this (using styled-components btw ) :
[image]

Comment: Styled component is prop based. You can pass title and description as boolean props.

Comment: Can u gimme some link with an example please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The Styled Components web site has an intro page for you to look at. https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started particularly the section on "Pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting"

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 ways to styling component in React.

Every approach have pros & cons(personally I use 4-th ways.)

**1.Inline Css**

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};
function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
```

**2. CSS in JS**

```
const Button = (props) => (
  <button className={ 'large' in props && 'large' }>
     { props.children }
     <style jsx>{`
        button {
          padding: 20px;
          background: #eee;
          color: #999
        }
        .large {
          padding: 50px
        }
     `}</style>
  </button>
)

/* Creates a regular button */
<Button>Hi</Button>

/* Creates a large button */
<Button large>Big</Button>
```

**3. Styled Components**

```
const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  background: papayawhip;
`;


render(
  <Wrapper>
    <Title>
      Hello World!
    </Title>
  </Wrapper>
);
```

**4. Css Modules (scss || sass)**

```
@width: 10px;
@height: @width + 10px;
#header {
  width: @width;
  height: @height;
}
```

**5. Stylable** - https://github.com/wix/stylable

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';

const Info = styled.div`
display: flex;
// etc.
${props => props.title && css`font-size: 15px`}
`
const Box = styled.div`
&:first-of-type {
// some more css 
}
`
// usage
<Info title>some info</Info>
```

I recommend you follow the official [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting) as stated in comments by @Mikkel